# jquery ui resizable div with large border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nkesh7e0/1/

```
enter code here
```

So I was playing around with jquery ui resizable and came up with the example in the fiddle link.

The problem I'm having is the locations of the anchors.  I want the anchors to be at the outer most corners when I have borders of any size on my div.  Currently the anchors are only at the corners of the element.  Is there any way to update the location of the anchors depending on my border size? Is this even possible?

Also, I want the anchors to work as they currently do, as in, no matter where they are located, they should only resize the div element itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is placing the content in a child element of the #elementResizable DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/1ajv6u54/

```
<div id='elementResizable'>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Full Name</h1>
        Title
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

As you can see, the content element's height won't resize. You can solve this by setting the height of the content element to 100%. Now the content element will resize to its parents' height and width.

The actual height of the content would be "100% + 2 * border-width" (100% + 100px). Since you need 100% as full height, you can set the content element's "box-sizing" attribute to "border-box". "border-box" adds "padding" and "border" to the elements width/height/min-width/min-height calculation.

**You can find the complete solution in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9puad2L6/).**

Comment: the example you put up doesn't work for resizing height

Comment: actually, I didn't notice the link at the bottom.  This is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: How would I get this to work if I set the box-sizing for #elementResizable to content-box instead of border-box?  I have a different scenario then my original question where the border on my div has to grow outward.